# My heap is working too slow

Tags: python, runtime, heap

So here is my code for min-heap. It's a part of my homework:

```
def heapify(i):
    global end,a
    l=2*i+1        
    if l>end:
        return None
    r=2*i+2
    minarg=i        
    if a[i]>a[l]:
        minarg=l
    if r<=end:
        if a[minarg]>a[r]: minarg=r
    if a[i]==a[minarg]:
        return None
    else:
        a[i],a[minarg]=a[minarg], a[i]
        heapify(minarg)

def buildHeap(start):
    global end,a
    if start*2+1>end:
        return None
    buildHeap(start*2+1)
    buildHeap(start*2+2)
    heapify(start)
```

It should be working, but I get time limit exceeded for large testcases. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can give the problem link

Comment: You can probably turn `buildHeap()` into a loop rather than a recursive function call.

Comment: Also, this is unrelated to your speed issue, but you shouldn't really be using global variables.

Comment: Even if you are using global variables, you don't need the `global` keyword there unless you need to rebind them

Answer (score 0):

Function calls in Python **take time**, recursion **takes space**.

To **save the time** of a recursion one usually transforms it into a loop. This usually requires to use a specialized "memory management" of the date to work on to **safe space**. You did that already (with... ehem... global variables) using an array/list.

If that is your homework, go ahead -- doable, but non-trivial.